# Python superclass calling subclasses

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I am trying to write a general class, such that this class (MLE) calls to a set of subclasses (NormMLE, BinMLE) which have similar functions (eg. set_param(), fit())

```
class MLE:
    def __init__(self, mclass):
        self.mle = mclass()

    def set_param(self, param):
        self.mle.set_param(param)

    def fit(self):
        self.mle.fit()

class NormMLE():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Initialize NormMLE"
        self.u = 0
        self.v = 0

    def set_param(self, param):
        self.u = param[0]
        self.v = param[1]
        print self.u
        print self.v

    def fit(self):
        return self.u*self.v

class BinMLE():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Initialize BinMLE"

    def set_param(self, param):
        self.u = param[0]
        self.v = param[1]
        self.w = param[2]
        print self.u
        print self.v
        print self.w        

    def fit(self):
        return self.u + self.v + self.w

nmle = MLE(NormMLE)
nparam = [1,2]
nmle.set_param(nparam)
print nmle.fit()

bmle = MLE(BinMLE)
bparam = [1,2,3]
bmle.set_param(bparam)
print bmle.fit()
```

The results return None when I call fit().

```
Initialize NormMLE
1
2
None
Initialize BinMLE
1
2
3
None
```

Now, I must have got the concept of OOP in python wrong. It seems that the param u, v and optionally w are not accessible in the subclass when the super class calls set_param() and fit() separately...

May I know what is the right way of achieving the OOP that I'd like to?

Comment: You don't have inheritance here, there is no superclass or subclasses. You have **containment**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MLE.fit()` method returns `None` because it has no explicit `return` statement:

```
def fit(self):
    self.mle.fit()
```

Perhaps you wanted to pass through the result from the `self.mle.fit()` call?

```
def fit(self):
    return self.mle.fit()
```

With that change, the output changes to:

```
Initialize NormMLE
1
2
2
Initialize BinMLE
1
2
3
6
```

Other than that, yes, you are not understanding OOP correctly yet. You do not have inheritance here. You have **containment**. Instances of `MLE` *contain* an instance of a different class, one that you expect implements specific methods (often called an *interface*). You have implemented the [*Delegation Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern); a facade class that delegates the actual work to a specialised contained object.

You could create an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) to document and verify the interface you expect:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MLEImplBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def set_param(self, param):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def fit(self):
        pass

class NormMLE(MLEImplBase):
    # ...

class BinMLE(MLEImplBase):
    # ...
```

This is not strictly necessary, but helpful when you add more implementations and accidentally misspell or forget one of the abstract methods.

However, the above *does* use inheritance. `MLEImplBase` is the superclass, with `NormMLE` and `BinMLE` being subclasses.